# What are some ways to figure out why your neural network classifies your data the way it does

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a couple opportunities to write a paper, or papers over some of the neural networks I have made.

I was wondering if there are anyways to figure out why the neural network classifies the data I have the way it does. As in, what features of the data the neural network is using to classify the data. The neural networks I'm using mostly consists of ltsm layers.

I have thought about ploting the neural network at everything output, but this doesn't really help to much. Just because there are so many weights that go to each node in a layer it makes it very hard to determine what's happening. I could plot the bias's but I don't know how much influence they have over the weights.

Another thing I considered was adjusting the the values of the input data a little bit at a time and seeing where the classification changes. Which this would work to some extent, but wouldn't allow to me to get the full picture of what the neural network is doing.

So any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: In NLP, there is a technique called `attention visualization` . How about starting from this? https://github.com/jessevig/bertviz

Comment: Please note that this is not a programming problem, general questions about AI/ML should go into the AI Stack Exchange, not in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Check https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/which-explainable-artificial-intelligence-techniques-are-there/24138#24138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Guided backprop from TorchRay. https://facebookresearch.github.io/TorchRay/attribution.html#module-torchray.attribution.guided_backprop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).